# Query to select the record description with the latest open date

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Case_ACTIONS

```
CASE_ID      SEQ_NUM      DATE_OPEN     DATE_DUE   CODE       DESCREPTION_J
153286253    64125995     9/21/2013     9/28/2013  23001954   有害事象連絡票
153286253    64125996     9/23/2013     9/29/2013  23001938   PMS-SAE/AE報告書
```

Table LM_ACTION_ITEM_TYPE

```
ACTION_TYPE_ID      ACTION_TYPE 
23001954           JP FU AE Report Frm
23001938           JP FU with pregnancy
```

I want to select DESCREPTION_J for the latest record of the types 'JP FU AE Report Frm' or 'JP FU with pregnancy '

The query I have written is :

```
select 
    description_j 
from 
    case_actions 
where  
    date_open = (select MAX(ca.date_open) 
                 from case_actions ca, LM_ACTION_ITEM_TYPE lat 
                 where ca.code = lat.action_type_id 
                   and lat.action_type IN ('JP FU AE Report Frm – Contact Record', 'JP FU AE Report Frm–Detail Invest. Frm','JP FU with pregnancy form') 
                   and ca.case_id = :P_LET_CASE_ID and ca.action_status = 1 
                   and ca.deleted is NULL)
```

and it is giving me incorrect data. Please help.

Comment: Did you run the sub-query by itself -- does it return results?  If yes did you then try and run the outer query with that value as a constant?  Did that work?  We can't really help more than that without example data and expected output.

Comment: Yes the Inner Query Returned a Unique date i.e the MAX date "MAX(ca.date_open)", so what I want Is I want the Value of another column of the same table which contains the field MAX(ca.date_open)

Comment: Do not deface your questions. There are no up-voted answers so you can just delete it if you really want to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You must correlate the outer query with the inner query, otherwise you may get case_actions that only have in common the date (and not the other filters in the subquery).

With this sample data:
[image]

With case_id=153286253 your query would give bbb and ddd. But ddd has a different case_id and code, which I don't think you want.

Adding and ca.case_id = case_actions.case_id to the inner query gives bbb, which I believe is the result you expect.

Comment: Why not? Could you please at least give a reason?

Comment: +1 No need.... you made edits, and added an image and now it is very clear.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should always give the entire table structure definition. 
Anyways, based on your sample query I could think of something. 
Try this.

```
select ca.description_j 
  from case_actions ca
 where ca.date_open = (select MAX(ca.date_open) 
                      from lm_action_item_type lat 
                     where ca.code = lat.action_type_id 
                       and lat.action_type IN ('JP FU AE Report Frm Contact Record', 'JP FU AE Report Frm Detail Invest. Frm','JP FU with pregnancy form') 
                       and ca.case_id = :P_LET_CASE_ID 
                       and ca.action_status = 1 
                       and ca.deleted is NULL)
```

Comment: Hi , I had also tried something similar but the problem with this is It can give Incorrect results .for example if the Inner query returns :9/23/2013  , the outer query will only match the date_open with this and that date can be not fulfilling the conditions of the inner query.

Comment: That's the problem exactly. You can either correlate both queries by case_id (see my answer) or repeat the filters in the outer query. The result would be the same.